# foreach cycle and lambda expression java

Tags: java, foreach

Dont understand what is wrong with syntaksis. Last line is not correct.

```
           rost.entrySet().stream()
            .map(entry -> rost.get(entry.getKey()))
            .map(each -> each.entrySet())
            .flatMap(Collection::stream)
            .map(entry -> entry.getValue())
            .map(each -> each.entrySet())
            .flatMap(Collection::stream)
            .map(entry -> entry.getValue())
            .map(each -> each.entrySet())
            .flatMap(Collection::stream)
            .map(entry -> entry.getValue()).forEach((group) ->
//// after this I have error
            {group.forEach(record->{filterCriteria1(record)})}
```

Comment: Remove the `{` and `}` around `{group.forEach(record->{filterCriteria1(record)})}`.

Comment: Also inside it: `record->{filterCriteria1(record)}`, remove the brackets there

Comment: When debugging, try spreading it out over multiple lines so you know what is actually causing the error (by line number) instead of it being unknown among 5 separate tasks all on the same line